# How are Hex and Binary parsed?

Tags: binary, hex

[HEX Article](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH01/CH01-2.html#HEADING2-1)

By this I mean,

In a program if I write this:

```
1111
```

I mean 15. Likewise, if I write this:

```
0xF
```

I also mean 15. I am not entirely sure how the process is carried out through the chip, but I vagely recall something about flagging, but in essence the compiler will calculate

```
2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = 15
```

Will 0xF be converted to "1111" before this calculation or is it written that somehow HEX F represents 15?

```
Or simply, 16^0 ? -- which obviously is not 15.
```

I cannot find any helpful article that states a conversion from HEX to decimal rather than first converting to binary.

---

Binary(base2) is converted how I did above (2^n .. etc). How is HEX(base16) converted? Is there an associated system, like base 2, for base 16?

I found in an article:

0x1234 =  1 * 16^3   +   2 * 16^2   +   3 * 16^1   +   4 * 16^0 = 4660

But, what if the number was 0xF, does this represent F in the 0th bit? I cannot find a straightforward example.

Comment: Note that many programming languages don't allow you to directly enter "character binary" (ie, stuff like `011010`).  Some variants of C/C++ permit the `0b` prefix for binary (ie, `0b011010`), but it's not standard.

Answer (score 1):

There are sixteen hexadecimal digits, 0 through 9 and A through F.

Digits 0 through 9 are the same in hex and in decimal.
0xA is 10<sub>10</sub>.
0xB is 11<sub>10</sub>.
0xC is 12<sub>10</sub>.
0xD is 13<sub>10</sub>.
0xE is 14<sub>10</sub>.
0xF is 15<sub>10</sub>.

For example:

0xA34F = 10 * 16<sup>3</sup> + 3 * 16<sup>2</sup> + 4 * 16<sup>1</sup> + 15 * 16<sup>0</sup>

Comment: Perfect, So 0xF = 15*16^0. I see. So, there is no conversion prior. Thank you.

Comment: Another quick question, albiet off topic. Are groups of 4 bits still represented as "nibbles?" The article I linked in the OP uses this jargon. Also, groups of 16bits are referred to as "words." Likewise, groups of 32bits are "double words."

Comment: @sherrellbc: Yes, that's fairly standard terminology.

Comment: Sometimes it's spelled "nybble", in sympathy with poor "byte".

Comment: What is a "word", on the other hand, is highly dependent on the processor and language you're using.  Never assume that a "word" is any particular length until you've found some specific verification.

Comment: @HotLicks: Of course, I was just making sure this terminiology was still in use. The article was written nearly two decades ago, so I wanted to make sure I would not proceed into the population using terminology that was deprecated.

Comment: Alas, words seldom disappear entirely from computer jargon (though they do get contorted quite frequently).